# Android home screen like navigation in view flipper

Tags: android

I am using `ViewFlipper` to navigate between screens. Each screen has 4 images in a grid. How to have similar functionality that is present on android `home screen` and `application menu screen` where user can quickly navigate to a page by pressing circle shaped buttons on top of screen. What I should use to have this effect? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would switch to using a `ViewPager`, available in the Compatibility Library: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Then you can use the `ViewPagerIndicator` library to achieve the effect that you're looking for (as well as giving you the choice of other styles of indicators): https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

[image: ViewPagerIndicator sample gallery]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example code: [Circle Flow Indicator](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

Using this you will get output:

[image]